# gactions login on WSL2 show xdg-open error

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

when I try to use `gactions login` on WSL2 terminal I'm getting this error

```
╰─ gactions login
[ERROR] exec: "xdg-open": executable file not found in $PATH
```

For gcloud or firebase it's just showing me a URL to open. Did someone managed to use this command?

Comment: Do you need to run this in a WSL2 environment? The binary has a Windows-compatible version. This is probably a bug/missing feature of gactions.

Comment: I'm using WSL2 for all dev stuff and keep all source code on linux partition. Also I'm using it with jovo which is using it under the hood and it can be incompatible when gactions installed on Windows path.

Comment: I've given the bug to the eng team. I think running the Windows-compatible binary in Command Prompt should work as a workaround for now.